# How to override a redirect set previously in request processing

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect, magento, response

This has bothered me for a while and I've avoided it but the time has come! Often when extending core Magento functionality, whether using the Event-Observer pattern or by overriding a controller (only if absolutely necessary!), the core code will have already set a redirect using `$this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);` or similar.

If I want to override that behaviour and have the response rendered in the current request/response cycle, how can I unset or nullify the redirect?

Looking through the type hierarchy to `Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract` which is the grandparent of `Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http`, there are methods to `clearHeaders()` which would wipe out the `Location` header that is controlled by `setRedirect()` but obviously it will wipe out any other headers as well.

Worse case would be to `getHeaders()`, `clearHeaders()` and then iterate through all the other Headers with `setHeader()`, but that seems painful.  Any suggestions welcome.

===============
**EDIT**

As pointed out by @xzyfer, the clearHeader() method does exist in some of the Magento editions.  For clients still working on older codebases, how would you recommend implementing this.  I'm hesitant to override `Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http` as it's such a key class...

Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: What version of magneto are you working on?

Comment: duh.  I'm normally the one bugging people to state what version :).  I'm using Magento Community v1.4.2 for this project

Comment: tbh there shouldn't be any reason why you couldn't replace the `Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract ` from your system with the a newer one with the `clearHeader()` function. If you download 1.4.2 from the magento website it comes packaged with Zend 1.10.8 which has the `clearHeader() method.

Comment: yup, I decided that was the best option too given that it's on the upgrade path anyway.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract` has a `clearHeader` method

```
$this->getResponse()->clearHeader('Location');
```

You'll also have to override the response code:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(200);
```

Just a guess from a quick look at the source of `Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract` assuming no other magic is going on in one of the child classes this should do the job.

Comment: Thanks... interesting that only exists in my copy of the Mage EE v1.9 codebase, not CE.  Ah, and I see it's in v1.5.0.1 - http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.5/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php

Comment: I'm sorry I don't completely understand you response, but is that to say the version of Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract used in the particular version of Mage doesn't have these methods?

Comment: yup, in Community Edition v1.4.2, `Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract` only has `clearHeaders()`, not `clearHeader()`  :(

Comment: Could you browse to the lib/Zend/Version.php and post the version number of the Zend Components. The 1.4.2 download from the magento website has 1.10.8 which has the `clearHeader()` method. They likely switched the external to a new tag though